# HTML tables (w/pagination & sorting) from non-model tabular data

Tags: django

I'm looking for some Django app that will facilitate the rendering of HTML tables (with pagination and per-column sorting) from tabular data ***that does not come from the app's database model***.  (All the table-rendering Django apps I have found so far seem to be designed to work with data coming via Django's ORM, but I want to render tabular data that is generated dynamically, and does not come from a database modeled through `models.py`.)  I'd be grateful for any suggestions/pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use django's built in pagination to achieve this. The Django's paginator does not limit the pagination to querysets. It expects an iterable.

From the documentation

> Note that you can give Paginator a list/tuple, a Django QuerySet, or
>   any other object with a `count()` or `__len__()` method. When determining
>   the number of objects contained in the passed object, Paginator will
>   first try calling `count()`, then fallback to using `len()` if the passed
>   object has no `count()` method. This allows objects such as Django’s
>   QuerySet to use a more efficient count() method when available.

More on [`Pagination` from the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#module-django.core.paginator)